# Regarding Security Audit Struts2 Application

Tags: java, hibernate, security, audit, fortify

In Forify Audit I'm getting issue, Access Control: Database. My app is for public access. Forify suggesting to check for proper user or user should be authenticated. But there is no login/logout kind of thing, means there is no user. the infected code is **:

**Abstract:** Without proper access control, the method transactions() in
DAOImpl.java can execute a SQL statement on line 147 that contains an
attacker-controlled primary key, thereby allowing the attacker to access unauthorized
records.

Source: Action.java:272 javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getParameter()

```
270 try {
271 String tehsil=request.getParameter("tehsilname");
272 String tehsilname=request.getParameter("tehsilcode");
273 sessionmap.put("tehsil", tehsilname);
274 **int month=Integer.parseInt(sessionmap.get("monthInString"));**
```

Sink: DAOImpl.java:147 org.hibernate.Query.setInteger()

```
145 query.setString(0, dist);
146 query.setInteger(1, month);
147 **query.setInteger(2, year);**
148 list = query.list();
149 }catch (Exception e) {
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. Problem with your code seem to be clearly described in the message. SO not going to decide for you if it is acceptable in your case or not - what else you are hoping to learn by asking this question?

Comment: In 1st code, at line 274 and in 2nd, at line 147 it shows an audit issue. "before going to execute your sql, authenticate first and make sure you are an authenticated user". But in my case there is no user for authentication purpose. Then how to fix this?

Comment: You need to decide *yourself* if it is a problem or not (SO can't help you with building security requirements for your app) and than either fix (should be ok SO question when you figure out what you want to achieve) or [suppers fortify alert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705134/how-to-supress-hp-fortify-critical-issues-in-java-code). There is nothing actionable for SO in current state of the post.